# How can I specify in cloudformation yaml file to use parameter value otherwise a default via FindInMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Say I have an ecs.yml file that specifies a lookup mapping for a hostname to set in an environment JAVA_OPTIONS value. The lookup key is an account Id value that is used for another setting. But I want to be able to override the use of the map in some usages of the template.

```
  AccId:
     Type: String
  AccountMap:
     DomainName:
          "01" :"https://production.example.com",
          "02" :"https://test.example.com",
          "03" :"https://pref.example.com"
```

and have

```
 TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
           ...<snip>...
           Environment: 
                 - Name: JAVA_OPTIONS
                   Value: !Sub
                     - "-DSERVER_HOST=${ServerHost} -DACC=${AccId}"
                     - !FindInMap [AccountMap, "ServerHost", !Ref "AccId"], AccId: !Ref AccId
```

But I'd like to have another template parameter i.e `SeverHostOveride` that overrides the use of the AccountMap lookup for setting the ServerHost if SeverHostOveride has a value.

```
  ServerHostOveride:
       Type:String 
       Default:''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using [Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html). I have used it for something simpler (code sample from a tutorial). Here's what I do

Set some conditions for DB

```
Conditions:
  isLarge:
    !Equals [!Ref EnvironmentSize, "LARGE"]
  isntLarge:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref EnvironmentSize, "LARGE"]]
  isRestore:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref SnapToRestore, ""]]
```

Under `Resources` I am creating a DB using those conditions (isntLarge & isRestore)

```
DB:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
Condition: isntLarge # added - only create the MySQL DB if its small/med
DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
Properties:
  AllocatedStorage: 5
  DBInstanceClass: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentSize, DB]
  DBName: !If [isRestore, !Ref "AWS::NoValue", !Ref DatabaseName]
  Engine: MySQL
  StorageType: gp2
  MasterUsername: !If [isRestore, !Ref "AWS::NoValue", !Ref DatabaseUser]
  MasterUserPassword: !If [isRestore, !Ref "AWS::NoValue", !Ref DatabasePassword]
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: !If [isRestore, !Ref SnapToRestore, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

Hope it helps.
PS: `EnvironmentSize` & `SnapToRestore` are defined in `Parameters` section in my yaml.

Comment: This was helpful thanks ended up with Conditions and a construct like     `ServerHost: !If [hasServerOverride, !Ref "ServerOverride", !FindInMap [AccountMap, "ServerHost", !Ref "AWS::AccId"]]`